# Relay access denied when sending mails to non-local addresses via SMTP

Tags: django, smtplib

The following snippet is used to send mails when a user registers

```
ht = str(emailcontent.replace( u'\ufeff',''))
html_content = ht.decode('utf-8-sig')
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, emailcontent.text, settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, [self.user.email]) 
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")                
msg.send()
```

This works well if I am sending to a local address but throws `Relay access denied` when the recipient is an external mail address (i.e. users with GMail or Yahoo accounts).

I need to send an HTML-based email whan a user registers. The content of this mails are stored in Database. Please suggest if there is any mistakes in the code above

Answer (score 2):

The error message is from the mail server that is asked to send the mail -- it only accepts mail for its own recipients (usually unless the sender authenticates himself somehow).

You may have to authenticate or use another mail server. This depends on the configuration of the mail server you use.

See the documentation about the SMTP backend configuration: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#smtp-backend

For the big picture, Wikipedia discusses Outgoing Mail servers in great detail:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP#Outgoing_mail_SMTP_server